# Printing shapefiles and shape type of feature classes and separating them by comma using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\\ArcGIS\\Data"

FCList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("")

for feature in FCList:

    print feature
```

This yields me a list of all of my .shp files, but I need it to recognize what geometry shape those shapefiles are and print them on the same line separated by a comma

Answer (score 3):

You could use [describe](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/describe-object-properties.htm) and then get the properties from the [feature class](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/featureclass-properties.htm)

Also if this help ListFeatureClasses also allows for a "feature_type" so if you really only want certain types you could provide a value for this parameter ([more info](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/listfeatureclasses.htm)).

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\ArcGIS\Data"
fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("")
for fc in fcList:
    desc = arcpy.Describe(fc)
     print(fc + ',' + desc.shapeType)
```